# Unable to show/hide a button element in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, button

I have this following html and css. And in the css I'm setting the *display:none* for the button. As this form is being shared across other pages I'd like to show this button on certain pages using jquery. I attempted to do it using ***$(".ui-multiselect.ui-widget.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all").show()*** but it didnt really work. Can someone please tell me if I'm doing something wrong here.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".ui-multiselect.ui-widget.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all").show();
});
```

```css
#userSearchForm .ui-multiselect {
    position: absolute;
    right: 31px;
    top: 26px;
    z-index: 100;
}
#userSearchForm .ui-multiselect {
    display: none;
}
#userSearchForm button {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 13px;
}
```

```html
    <form method="post" action="bulkOperations.html?execution=e23s1" id="userSearchForm">
            <select multiple="multiple" autocomplete="off" name="userSearchBean.searchCriteria" id="searchFilter" style="display: none;"><option value="userStatus">User status</option><option value="accountStatus">Account status</option><option value="maidenName">Maiden Name</option></select>
            <button type="button" class="ui-multiselect ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" aria-haspopup="true" style="width: 231px;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s"></span><span>Add More Search Criteria</span></button><input type="hidden" value="1" name="_userSearchBean.searchCriteria" autocomplete="off">
            <table width="100%" cellspacing="1" id="userSearchFormTable" class="yui">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <div class="info center" style="position:relative;">All searches use a 'starts with' algorithm</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td class="filter" colspan="2">
                        <input type="submit" value="Search" name="_eventId_searchUsers" class="redBtn" id="searchUsers" autocomplete="off">
                        <a id="cleanUserSearchForm" class="whiteBtn" href="javascript:void(0);">Clear</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: Works just fine for me when including jQuery -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/7gwupuv0/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by just copy-n-pasting your code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fesoy/twm76n7h/)
Make sure you included `jquery` in your files or else it won't work.